# simple design for mechanized home automation devices to stop at limits

Tags: home-automation, mechanical, actuator

can you point me to any existing designs or ideas for simple DIY type mechanism to ... for example... roll up/ roll down  a motorized movie screen and stop when it gets to some  specific limits.

i can imagine putting contact switches  at each end of travel but then the moving 'thing' has to physically push on the switches and they would be visible with wires etc.

Comment: this is more about how do you make sensor cables neat and hidden. look inside some home electronics for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Many commercial systems of this type use a system similar to what is used in garage door openers. This is a screw mechanism that is driven by the motor at the same time as the actual output drive.

There are adjustable limit switches that trip when the screw reaches arbitrary points.

Because this mechanism is completely contained in the motor drive enclosure, there aren't any external limit switches required. Thus - no external wires for the limit switches.

Kinda hard to explain without pictures. Google will give you some guidance.

[Edit]

Here is a short video from Google that shows such a mechanism in a Craftsman Garage Door Opener.  Notice that the central screw has a traveller that moves from one end to the other.  The adjustment screws move the limit switches either forward or backwards to set the location where the traveller meets the switches.
[Craftsman Garage Door Opener](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I28k1uY928)

[Edit 2]

Here is an expired patent of a similar system but with two separate travellers.  This may be easier for you to fabricate a DIY version.  [Patent via Google](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5299678)

Comment: thanks for the tips. i actually am familiar with the mechanism you describe in edit 1:  i opened my garage door opener a while back and was impressed with that mechanism.   however it would be hard to fabricate that as a DIY.  Im looking at the patent link you sent in Edit 2, it doesnt seem any easier to do as a DIY Project :)

Comment: This DIY project can be done.  Not a slam-dunk but doable.  All-thread rod is available in 10-32 or 1/4-20.  The bearings can be simple holes drilled into Delrin or nylon. The stops that hold the rod in place axially can be nuts that are either doubled-up (jam-nuts) or crazy-glued in place on the rod.  Use flat washers between the nuts & the Delrin.  The traveller nut can have a rod brazed to one edge of the nut - this rides on rails that stop the nut from turning.  This same rod is what trips the limit switches.  The only hard part is coupling that threaded rod to the output of the drive.

Comment: thanks. maybe i will try one.  regarding connecting the 'device' to the output of the drive... i agree that would be the hard part.  how would i do that with the necessry precision?   it seems easier said then done to maybe put a gear on the ouput shart of the drive and mesh it to a gear on the threaded rod of the 'device'?  maybe a belt drive requires less precision?    

one thing i have learned is that it is hard ot do anything too precise at home. i built a motorized garage storage platform with a winch, cables, pulleys etc and threaded it thru garage ceiling joists. lots of friction :(